# Fundamental period of $x [ n ] = \cos( πn/ 2) \cos( πn/ 4)$, trig expansion

Tags: trigonometry

$x [ n ] = \cos( πn/ 2) \cos( πn/ 4)$

->

as $x[n] = \frac{1}{2} \cos(3π \frac{n}{4}) + \frac{1}{2} \cos(\frac{πn}{4})$

Trig formula is: $\cos^2 \theta = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} cos(2 \theta)$

So I don't get where $3π \frac{n}{4}$ comes from

This is from [here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ipollak/ece301/FALL11/homework_solutions/hw2_sol.pdf), (g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using formula$$2\cos A \cos B=\cos (A+B)+\cos (A-B)$$

> $$2\cos (\frac{nπ}{2}) \cos (\frac{nπ}{4})=\cos (\frac{nπ}{2}+\frac{nπ}{4})+\cos (\frac{nπ}{2}-\frac{nπ}{4})$$$$2\cos (\frac{nπ}{2}) \cos (\frac{nπ}{4})=\cos (\frac{3nπ}{4})+\cos (\frac{nπ}{2})$$